# how to run shell commands inside docker container?

Tags: python, docker-container, docker-exec

```
import docker

# Initialize the Docker client
client = docker.from_env()

# Define Docker run options
docker_run_options = {
    'name': 'container-name',
    'user': 'dafoamuser',
    'mounts': [
        {
            'type': 'bind',
            'source': 'D:/Dafoam/oneraM6',
            'target': '/home/dafoamuser/mount'
        }
    ],
    'working_dir': '/home/dafoamuser/mount',
    'detach': True,
    'tty': True,
    'stdin_open': True,
    'command': 'bash'
}

# Run the Docker container with specified options
container = client.containers.run(
    'dafoamimage:latest',
    **docker_run_options
)

# Execute the mpirun command inside the container
mpirun_command = 'mpirun -np 8 python runScript_v2.py 2>&1 | tee logOpt.txt'
exec_cmd = container.exec_run(mpirun_command, tty=True, privileged=True)
print(f"Command: {mpirun_command}\nOutput:\n{exec_cmd.output.decode('utf-8')}")

# Stop and remove the container (if needed)
container.stop()
container.remove()
```

I am trying to execute a python script named runScript_v2.py inside container's shell using the above python script.
But I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\yesbo\.conda\envs\py39env\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py:219: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Blowfish has been deprecated
  "class": algorithms.Blowfish,
Command: mpirun -np 8 python runScript_v2.py 2>&1 | tee logOpt.txt
Output:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun was unable to find the specified executable file, and therefore
did not launch the job.  This error was first reported for process
rank 0; it may have occurred for other processes as well.

NOTE: A common cause for this error is misspelling a mpirun command
      line parameter option (remember that mpirun interprets the first
      unrecognized command line token as the executable).

Node:       c537205732b5
Executable: python
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
8 total processes failed to start
```

How can I fix this? From cmd I can run this mpirun command easily without any errors. But when I run my python script it gives me the error.

Comment: Have you installed mpirun and Python within that container?

Comment: Can you put it as the `command` in the container spec rather than trying to execute against the running container?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I can run mpirun command inside container's bash shell using cmd that means its installed.

Comment: @C.Nivs could you please elaborate? Sorry I am a newbie, i did not get it.

Comment: I misunderstood the error output. It seems to say that python executable isn't found

Comment: I have added full paths for both mpirun and python, and now I can run runScript_v2.py file. 
`mpirun_command = '/home/dafoamuser/dafoam/packages/openmpi-3.1.6/opt-gfortran/bin/mpirun -np 8 /home/dafoamuser/dafoam/packages/miniconda3/bin/python runScript_v2.py'`

But It should not ask for paths. Looks like all paths are reset or it is not running commands at correct place or something else, idk what...

Comment: if I use windows command prompt, I don’t need to provide full paths. In windows command prompt, I can simply put my commands as follows:

`C:\Users\yesbo>docker run -it --name container-name --rm -u dafoamuser --mount "type=bind,src=D:/Dafoam,target=/home/dafoamuser/mount" -w /home/dafoamuser/mount dafoamimage:latest bash`
`dafoamuser@ed3136410e4f:~/mount$mpirun -np 8 python runScript_v2.py | tee logOpt.txt`

Now I don’t know what I am doing wrong in python script. It should not ask for paths.